# Change a div on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `front-end`. Now, Here I have `3 divs` which will be on the same page.and the position will also be same. it is like toggling .
So at the start this will be the div that I will show

```
<div text-angular id="htmlEditorId" >Abc</div>
```

then there is button whick is like

```
<button class="col-xs-3 btn btn-default" ng-click="changeTab()">NextTab </button>
```

On click of that button

```
<div text-angular id="secon">abcd</div>
```

this div should be shown and not the previous one.

And on again click of that button a third div

```
<div text-angular id="third">azzzbcd</div>
```

this should be seen and again on click first one should show . Its like a round robin fashion .

Now what I tried is  using `ng-show` and `ng-if`.  Can any one help me with this?

```
$scope.changeTab = function() {
     $scope.showfirst = true;
  $scope.showsecond = false;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. Remember that SO is here to help you learn by debugging code you've written, not to write code for you

Comment: yes, I will update that code.

Comment: why extra `"` in each div?

Comment: Thats a typo mistake.

Comment: Can you create a **short** [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) demo for your code? It will much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I tried it using the show and hide

Comment: @Rory McCrossan please see updated function.

Comment: @DavidThomas UPDATED the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you can do it in many ways, for example:

**In the controller**
Define a scoped variable (bindable with the front-end)

```
$scope.showView = "firstView"
```

Define also a function:

```
$scope.changeView = function(value) {
     $scope.showView = value;
}
```

**In the html page** define your divs and button

```
<button ng-click="changeView('secondView')">Chage View</button>

<div ng-show="showView == 'firstView'">abcd</div>
<div ng-show="showView == 'secondView'">abcd</div>
```